# What does ConditionalAttribute on an Attribute do?

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes, release-builds, debug-build

I know what `ConditionalAttribute` does.

The docs say it can also be applied to a class, if it's derived from `Attribute`:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public class FooAttribute : Attribute { }
```

*But how does that custom attribute behave?* (Is it stripped out of a release build?)

Comment: There's another question about: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1412838/4730201

Comment: @RicardoPontual No that doesn't address the issue. I want to know what it does when applied to an `Attribute` specifically.

Comment: [Applying ConditionalAttribute to an attribute indicates that the attribute should not be emitted to metadata unless the conditional compilation symbol is defined.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) What does that mean??

Comment: Interesting.. what I could understand is that the attribute is omitted, like it does not exists in class. Some tests can confirm that.

Comment: @RicardoPontual How did you test? Thanks for the idea, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RicardoPontual's comment gave me an idea.

I did this:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public class FooAttribute : Attribute { }

[Foo]
public class Bar { }
```

I compiled in *debug mode*, and loaded the DLL in ILSpy (it's a disassembler). This is what I found, as expected:

```
[Foo]
public class Bar { }
```

Then I compiled in *release mode*, and loaded that DLL in ILSpy. This is what I found:

```
public class Bar { }
```

The `Bar` class was not decorated this time!

*So, the answer is that when you decorate some custom attribute with `Conditional`, then that attribute itself becomes conditional in the same way.*

That's the behavior I wanted. I initially thought to derive from `ConditionalAttribute`, but it's sealed. Instead you need to decorate your custom attribute.

Comment: Great, the test answered the question. I could imagine some useful things, like implement a logic in runtime depending on whether the assembly was compiled debug or release, just inspecting the presence of a custom attribute:
`if (typeof(MyType).IsDefined(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), false))`